# How to update photo in Active Directory using PHP ldap_modify

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to update a bunch of user photos in our Windows Active Directory using PHP and ldap_modify.  I get no errors but the photo is not updated either.  Anything glaring that I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
//previously have connected to AD and have $conn resource. I also have correct $dn.
$photofile='/var/www/temp/mynewphoto.jpg';
$data=file_get_contents($photofile);
$changes['photo']='data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data);
if(!ldap_modify($conn, $dn, $changes)){
    $enum=ldap_errno($conn);
    $msg=ldap_err2str( $enum );
    echo "Photo change Failed for {$dn}. {$msg}".'<br />'.PHP_EOL.printValue($ldapInfo);
}
else{               
    echo "Photo Updated for  : {$dn} : {$rec['dn']}<br />".PHP_EOL;
    $cnt+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want the `photo` attribute? By default Outlook, etc. looks at the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute, which is just a byte array of the file (not base64 encoded). Something like this:

```
$changes['thumbnailPhoto'] = $data;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was all it was. You are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//previously have connected to AD and have $conn resource. I also have correct $dn.
$photofile='/var/www/temp/mynewphoto.jpg';
$data=file_get_contents($photofile);
$changes= ['thumbnailPhoto' => [$data]];
if(!ldap_modify($conn, $dn, $changes)){
    $enum=ldap_errno($conn);
    $msg=ldap_err2str( $enum );
    echo "Photo change Failed for {$dn}. {$msg}".'<br />'.PHP_EOL.printValue($ldapInfo);
}
else{               
    echo "Photo Updated for  : {$dn} : {$rec['dn']}<br />".PHP_EOL;
    $cnt+=1;
}
```